# Handle SimpleXMLRPCServer calls and Asyncore.dispatchers events from the same event-loop

Tags: python, event-handling, twisted, rpc, asyncore

How can I handle Asyncore.dispatcher(s) and SimpleXMLRPCServer events from the same event-loop?

P.S. I already know that some of you might recommend Twisted for this, but the problem with Twisted is that it is a little bit too high-level library for my needs. In particular I am doing UDP flow-control by overriding Asyncore.dispatcher.writable() method that depends on timers. Not sure if/how this could be doable in Twisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Twisted for this :-).  You can't put `SimpleXMLRPCServer` into an asynchronous loop; it's synchronous code, which expects to block.

Flow-control with Twisted, even with UDP, is easy.  Rather than overriding a method like `writable()`, your [`DatagramProtocol`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.protocol.DatagramProtocol.html) can call methods like `stopReading` / `stopWriting` / `startReading` / `startWriting` on their `transport` attribute.  You can see these methods [here](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.udp.Port.html#id139).

Comment: SimpleXMLRPCServer uses asynchronous IO for reading, while writing is blocking. Anyway, while Twisted seems to be high-level library it is still possible to do all the same things as in low-level asyncore. I suppose I could inherit from Twisted's FileDescriptor to get the low level IO features or use Twisted Prodcuers. The latter option even seems better solution. Thanks.